# Plotting chart with varying Data series

Tags: excel, charts

I am looking to plotting a car variant price comparison chart where the chart Y axis would be amount currency.
X Axis would be different car brands like Honda Hyundai, Toyota etc.

My plot would be the price for each car variant from low to high [As per this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2D9J.png)

Note:
Number of variants in the brands may be different so that way the series in the plots will be different in length/size.

Comment: when i want to plot the pricing on the y Axis, stacked graph dont work first price point is actual price, there on only the incremental prices stacked on top on one another. though i want to show series line between the variant prices, i dont want the lowest variant start all the way from "0" position on the axis. this will make the bar look floating.
Thanks Vikram

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hi Nurgasemetey, I dont have any code written. I am collating data from web in the tabular fashion as per the image i have shared. I want to plot the graph in Excel.